# How to access function parameter from inner function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I access to response parameter inside function .exec(function(err, repl) { ? Is it possible without creating local variable?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();


// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  client.multi([
    ['get', 'a'],
    ['get', 'b']
  ]).exec(function(err, repl) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(repl[0]);
    response.end('Repl: ' + repl[0].toString());
  });
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access it. Parameters are automatically treated as local variables, and an inner function can access its containing function's local variables (unless it shadows them with its own variables with the same name).